# How to write to the second column in .CSV using batch script?

Tags: csv, batch-file, for-loop, export-to-csv

I'm trying to read a column of numbers from the .txt file and place them in the .csv in the second column.

How to define the second column in batch?

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%i in (issn.txt) do (
 >>"anzahl.csv" echo %%i
```

Comment: I don't think you can define the second column in batch. I would loop through each line, and re-write it as <existing line> + <second column>

Comment: I don't have any plans how to do it.

Comment: IMHO Insufficient information about the files. BTW `"tokens=1 delims= "` are default values that can be omitted. The opening parenthesis following do has no closing pendant. To have an empty first column simply `echo ,%%i`

Comment: @LotPings   the first column isn't empty. It's already filled

Comment: IMHO still insufficient information about the files. Does the csv file have a header? How do you want to associate the entries? One by one? You should read what a [mcve] is

Comment: the entries should be associated one by one and the csv file doesn't have a header. The first column is filled with numbers

Comment: A few lines showing typical input from the two files and expected result would clarify matters enormously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create file `New-Anzahl.csv` which has empty col2's when number of entries in `issn.txt` is less than `anzahl.csv` count. Other way around issn.txt overhang is truncated.

```
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "FileA=anzahl.csv"
Set "FileB=issn.txt"
<%FileB% (For /f "delims=" %%A in (%FileA%) Do (
    Set "B="&Set /P "B="
    Echo:%%A,!B!
)) >New-%FileA%
```